# Alter in PL SQL Loop

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

I just started learning PL/SQL an hour ago... I'm trying to set profile settings dynamically... I select distinct profile names from dba_users and I'm trying to run an alter profile command for each profile name. How can I get the alter command to work in a loop like this?

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> declare
  2  begin
  3     for rec in (select distinct Profile from dba_users) loop
  4       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter profile :1 LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED' using rec.PROFILE;
  5       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter profile :1 LIMIT PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX UNLIMITED' using rec.PROFILE;
  6     end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00931: missing identifier
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I saw documentation about the `using` keyword which apparently wasn't what I needed. Instead I needed to use string concatenation `||`.

Here's the working version:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare

begin
    for rec in (select distinct Profile from dba_users) loop
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter profile ' || rec.PROFILE || ' LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter profile ' || rec.PROFILE || ' LIMIT PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX UNLIMITED';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: `using` is normally want you want for dynamic SQL, in combination with bind variables, to avoid SQL injection. As you've discovered though, you can't use bind variables with DDL statements, hence you have to fall back to concatenation in this case.